# Append template string of html to DOM onClick

Tags: javascript

I want to show a modal when I click on and icon. The modal template is inside a template string in my js.

**html**

```
<i id="settings-icon" class="fa fa-cog" onClick='attachModal()'></i>
```

**javascript**

```
const attachModal = () => {
  const modal =  `
    <div class='modal>
      Modal
    </div>
  `;
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', modal);
};
```

There is not error messages however I don't see the modal code in the dom after I click

Comment: What happens when you add the second ` so its: `class='modal'`?

Comment: @imvain2 Good eye! However it still isn't in the dom

Comment: I created this working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e5ymcq63/ My only changes were fixing that modal class, adding a character to click on and creating a modal class to visually see it being added.

Comment: Instead of adding the HTML dynamically, why don't you just put it in the HTML and changes its `display` style?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using `[innerHTML][1]` and [`node.remove()][1]` for this since the modal is only either supposed to be visible or hidden. You can append the modal code to the html by using `document.body.innerHTML += modal`. Using `+=` will concatenate the new HTML to the existing one without replacing/removing any of the existing HTML.

If `isModal` is true (meaning the modal is already visible) then use `isModal.remove()` which is a method that a child node can use to remove itself from it's parent (in this case `body`).

By adding the logic that both hides or shows the modal conditionally, you can reuse this function in what I assume will be a close or cancel button within the modal.

*Note: I use a `p` tag instead of an `i` tag for demonstrative purposes. The `p` tag is not crucial to the solution.

```js
const attachModal = () => {

  var isModal = document.getElementById('modal')
  
   const modal =  `<div id="modal">
     MODAL
  </div>`
  
  if (isModal){
    isModal.remove()
  } else {
    document.body.innerHTML += modal 
  }
};
```

```html
<p id="settings-icon" class="fa fa-cog" onClick='attachModal()'>test</p>
```